# Reading a ConfigurationSection

Tags: c#, service, config, app-config

I'm writing a Windows service that needs some information from the app.config - I know I could use `AppSettings`, but I'm trying to understand config sections a little better.

I've modified my App.Config:

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"
                      version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>

  <configSections>
    <section name="config"
             type="MyNamespace.MyConfigurationSection"/>
  </configSections>

  <config aNumber="1"
          aBoolean="false"/>

</configuration>
```

and created the following class:

```
public sealed class MyConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("aNumber", DefaultValue = 1, IsRequired = false)]
    public int Number
    {
        get { return (int) this["aNumber"]; }
        set { this["aNumber"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("aBoolean", DefaultValue = false, IsRequired = false)]
    public bool Boolean
    {
        get { return (bool) this["aBoolean"]; }
        set { this["aBoolean"] = value; }
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to access it like this:

```
public MyConfigurationSection ConfigSection
{
    get
    {
        var configurationSection = Configuration.GetSection("config");
        return (MyConfigurationSection) configurationSection;
    }
}

private static Configuration Configuration
{
    get { return ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None); }
}
```

Everything works fine until I get to the `(MyConfigurationSection) configurationSection` cast.  I'm getting back a `DefaultSection` from my call to `GetSection()`, and the cast fails.

Where have I gone astray?

Comment: couldn't you think of a better name for the configsection than "config"

Comment: This is a mockup.  I'm not really using "aBoolean" and "aNumber", either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The catch here is, you have to use the type value as "Namespace.ClassName, Namespace" in section configuration in app.config and more importantly the configSections must be the first child of the root configuration element in your app.config

Below configuration might work for you:

```
<configuration>
      <!-- <configSections> is moved to first child of <configuration> -->
      <configSections>
        <section name="config"
                 type="MyNamespace.MyConfigurationSection, MyNamespace"/>
      </configSections>

      <config aNumber="1"
              aBoolean="false"/>

      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"
                          version="v4.0"/>
      </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You were right on both points.  Rearranged things *and* changed the 'type' attribute and it works like a charm.  Well done, mate.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, although didn't check,

```
type="MyNamespace.MyConfigurationSection"/>
```

Should be

```
type="<Namespace.ClassName>,<Namespace>"/>
```

Comment: This was part of the problem, but I also needed to reorder the app.config as in the marked answer.

Answer (score 0):

config is a reserved word and cannot be used for the name of a configuration section. You also shouldn't name a variable Boolean.

Try this following example:

```
using System.Configuration;

namespace ConfigSectionSample
{
    internal class MyConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        public static MyConfigurationSection Current
        {
            get
            {
                return (MyConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("myConfig");
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("aNumber", IsRequired = true)]
        public int Number
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)this["aNumber"];
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("aBoolean", IsRequired = true)]
        public bool Boolean
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)this["aBoolean"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the following app,config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="myConfig" type="ConfigSectionSample.MyConfigurationSection, ConfigSectionSample"></section>
  </configSections>

  <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>

  <myConfig aNumber="1" aBoolean="false" />
</configuration>
```

And get the values like this:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Number: " + MyConfigurationSection.Current.Number);
        Console.WriteLine("Boolean: " + MyConfigurationSection.Current.Boolean);
        Console.ReadLine();
```